# jqGrid sort icon manipulation

Tags: jquery, sorting, jqgrid, icons

How can you toggle the sort icons on/off?  From [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601476/is-it-possible-to-hide-or-manipulate-the-jqgrid-sort-icons) post I saw this seems to turn them off: `$("#gbox_list .s-ico span").hide()`.  But this corresponding code did NOT seem to turn them on again: `$("#gbox_list .s-ico span").show()`.  ??

And how can you manipulate them?  Ie: How can you programatically set the second column to show the asc sort arrow (and not show the arrow on other columns)?

Comment: This was also asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3807719/jqgrid-sort-icon-displayed-when-no-sorting-performed/

Comment: I actually asked that question :-)  Slightly different scenario though - that was concerned just with the initial page load when no sorting was performed..

Answer (score 0):

have you tried:
$("#gbox_list .s-ico span").toggle();

click 1 should hide/show and click 2 should reverse.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 $("#gview_"+id).find(".ui-jqgrid-hdiv .ui-jqgrid-htable .ui-jqgrid-labels .ui-jqgrid-sortable .s-ico").show();
```

where "id" is id of the grid