# How can I turn off setting default sorting pointer in jqgrid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, grid

I'll explain it with an example. I've been investigating a lot of jsfiddle representations of jqgrid and all of them had this tiny sign in the header of the first column. Look:
[image]

I have found (in one of the jsfiddles) that  "**multiselect: *true***" can make this sign disappear, but that is not the case for me cause I needn't multiselect mode. So is there another way to hide this little sign ?

Comment: probably you mean `multiselect: true` and not `multiselect: false`?

Comment: yes, you're right. Just edited this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug in case of usage no `sortname` or `sortname: ""` which is the same. Some time ago I posted [the pull request](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/pull/624/) which fixed it. The pull request is merged to the main code of jqGrid, so the next version of jqGrid (higher as the current 4.6.0) will don't have the problem.

I can suggest you two workarounds. The first one: usage of `rownumbers: true` with is good in general. The second workaround I described in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25329337/315935). One can use `lastsort: "0"` instead of default `lastsort: 0` option. It's a hack only, but it fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately I am using jqGrid version 4.4.4 and lastsort: "0" fix doesn't work for this version. I checked out this fix in one of the jsfiddles and it really works for version 4.6.0 .

Comment: @AntonKasyanchuk: You are welcome! You should always mentions which version you use if you don't use the last one. The version 4.4.4 is really old. You can try to makes the same or close changes in `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` like I desribed in [the pull request](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/commit/328ddfface3fa0cb41db04c9c1a336380c3a0571) if you can't update jqGrid which you use.